# Do Objective-C properties (self.foo) have much more overhead than using ivars (_foo)?

Tags: objective-c, properties, compiler-optimization, ivar

I prefer to write "self.foo" instead of "_foo", mostly for style reasons. In theory self.foo means a function call, while _foo doesn't. I think this ok because it's unlikely to matter much for most code.

My question is: does the compiler optimize this to the same thing anyways? Maybe it can't, due to method swizzling? Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3):

No, the compiler doesn't optimize it to just an instance variable access. It cannot optimize it, because the class could have a subclass that overrides the getter method. (Note that subclasses can be created at runtime!)

However, you shouldn't worry about the message-sending overhead unless you've profiled your code and determined that it's a bottleneck.

Comment: To add more info, keep in mind that the synthesized property methods will include code for KVO and if the property is marked as `atomic` it will add code for that as well. And back in the MRC days, the methods added code for proper memory management. So yes, there is much more overhead than simple access to an ivar. But as Rob stated, don't worry about any of it unless you have a proven bottleneck due to using the property's methods over direct ivar access.

Comment: [KVO adds setter overrides at runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html), not compile-time. Also, KVO doesn't override getters, only setters. [Core Data requires custom getters to invoke `willAccessValueForKey:` and `didAccessValueForKey:`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/didAccessValueForKey:).